# PHP. Working with files on FTP server

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I have two FTP servers. In first server i will run the script(filemoving.php) which will connect via FTP to second server(**second server not supporting php**) and move files from 1 folder to 2. But i am getting error

**Warning: ftp_put(/2/1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

here is my code, please tell me what i am doing wrong.

*filemoving.php*

```
//$ftp_conn its connection id, connection was established
$folder = '/1';
$target_folder = '/2';
$files_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, $folder);

foreach($files_list as $remote_file) {
    ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $target_folder . '/' . basename($remote_file), FTP_ASCII);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know /1 and /2 without anything else is a valid path..

Comment: Please, try to use [realpath()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_realpath.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and thank you for answers. I have to use **ftp_rename** function instead **ftp_put** - that's it :)